# Minimize window event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to detect if the user clicked on the minimize button a website? I need it to raise an event for my web game. 
I've used

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   //TODO: Add event here...
}};
```

but really all it detects is if I've manipulated the width and or height of the window. It doesn't do anything if I click on the minimize window button.

I hope someone has stumbled onto this situation and can help me figure this out. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why minimise but not tab switch etc.?

Comment: I haven't personally done it myself but I've found this link, uses javascript not JQuery - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847108/is-it-possible-to-tell-if-a-user-has-my-page-minimized-or-the-inactive-tab

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552118/jquery-toggle-on-window-minimize/552183#552183